# Is index necessary in temp-table?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am linking two tables existing in Database using Temp Table criteria. Is it necessary to create an index while creating temp-tables in Progress?

Comment: not necessary but recommended

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary but it is a good idea!

If you care about your performance you should add NO-UNDO as well as the correct indices to your temp-tables. This has been stated in numerous "best practices" documentations.

It might be hard to know beforehand if there are performance gains with an added index. But: the cost of adding the index is usually very low. Just add index to match how you query the temp-table!

In version 11.6 the XREF compile argument has added support for temp-table index usage.

Comment: If you define a temp-table like a database table you get all the indexes of the database table unless you specify an index in the temp-table definition. All indexes of the original table may be too much overhead if that table has a lot of indexes

Comment: @carlverbiest Yes. And it might also be the wrong indexes depending on your queries - perhaps they differs from the queries on the database tables.